# disable iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I know this may be really silly - but how can I disable the iphone simulator in xcode? I just want to try a few things and dont care about the view, only the console. I seriously looked everywhere and nada.

Thanks!

Comment: Why does it matter if the simulator is running?

Comment: Just slightly annoying when it's up all the time and it takes more time when it's loading..I am just interested in the console output at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run your code somewhere. It either runs on the device, or on the simulator. You cannot run your code on the console alone.

Answer (score 0):

just "build", not "build and run" (shortcut: command + B).

Comment: Build doesn't run the code - I want to run it but with no simulator...I know it doesnt make a lot of sense cause the code launches the view, but still I was curious if this is possible. In most of my testing, I dont really care about the view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your model, and don't care about the view, create and use unit tests. But even then it needs to run the code somewhere...